# Cannot add Google Play Location Service as dependency to my Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, google-play-services

I tried to add the Google location Service to my Android Project by referencing the official [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

As the tutorial said I added the following line to the dependencies section in the Project Gradle file.

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
```

But when i resynced the project i got the following error

```
Error:(19, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:/home/aslampr07/Desktop/UrbanMeals/build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and Gradle Version 4.1.
How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add maven repository in your app gradle file. Try by doing these steps. Open the build.gradle file for your application. Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example: 
`allprojects {repositories {jcenter()maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}}}`
Avoid using + in your dependencies as it android studio will try to update dependencies every 24 hours. Also replace compile by implementation for low APK size.
**Edit 1:**
As you told maven repository did not worked.
Check your project settings by going to Android Studio.
Click on file
click on project structure
There will option of Project in sidebar. Tap on it.
Check for the gradle and andrpid plugin version.
Put these values
Gradle Version - 4.1
Android plugin version - 3.0.1
Android Plugin Repository - jcenter,google()
Default Library Repository - jcenter, 'https://maven.google.com'

Reply me if it works

Comment: Added the maven url, still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
 please try this        
 Add in Build.gradel at app lavel

dependencies {
 Implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
     to all sub-projects/modules.

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
  }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to add the entire google service, i only wanted to add the location service.